# Code a dummy variable if a certain date falls within a start date and an end date

Tags: r, date

I have a DF1 which contains a bunch of observations with a start date (startdate) and an end date (endate): both of the them are in y/m/d format. I would like to check whether observations from another dataset (DF2, that has a date variable as well) fall within the interval of `DF1$startdate` and `DF1$endate.`

In practice I would like to have that:
If each `DF2$date` is included in one of the time intervals of each `DF1$startdate` and `DF1$endate`.

Unfortunately, I cannot do it manually as it would take ages due to the number of observations.

I tried with this but it does not seems to work:

```
for (i in 1:length(DF2$date))
{ 
for (j in 1:length(DF1$startdate)){
if (DF1$startdate[j] <= DF2$date[i] 
  <= DF1$enddate[j]){
  DF2 = append(frcab_content_lemma_ngram_postprocessed$HasMid, 1)
   } 
  else {DF2$HasMid = append(DF2$HasMid, 0}
   }
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some example data for us to play around with that mimics your actual data?

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect place to use `dplyr`. What I do here is `left_join` DF1 and DF2 together so we can use variables from each, then use `mutate()` to add a new variable `'hasMid'` whose value is set depending on the outcome of the `if_else` statement:

```
library(dplyr)
DF1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2),
                  startdate = c(10, 15, 12, 5, 6, 21),
                  enddate = c(11, 25, 18, 7, 19, 30))
DF2 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), date = c(8, 21, 19))

x <- DF1 %>%
    left_join(DF2, by = c('x' = 'x')) %>%
    mutate(hasMid = if_else(startdate <= date & date <= enddate, TRUE, FALSE))
```

Output:

```
  x startdate enddate date hasMid
1 1        10      11    8  FALSE
2 2        15      25   21   TRUE
3 3        12      18   19  FALSE
4 1         5       7    8  FALSE
5 1         6      19    8   TRUE
6 2        21      30   21   TRUE
```

For the future, it's much easier to answer problems like this if you give people a minimal reproducible example:

Comment: Thanks, however the I cannot left join the two by a "x" (e.g. even a coutner from 1 to n). Because DF2 has just 89 observations (bunch of events) while DF1 has 21840 observations.

Comment: You should be able to. The point of a ```left_join``` is that you keep each row on the left hand side (DF1) and join it to the corresponding row on the right hand side (DF2) by the specified variable. If there are multiple rows in DF1 that match one row in DF2, the DF2 row will be joined multiple times. I've updated my example to show this.

Comment: If this doesn't work, then I don't think I understand your problem. In that case it would help if you provide a minimally reproducible example with an example of your data.

Comment: Ok I got it! Thanks! The main problem though is that I do not have any "common" variable in the two df that I can use for "by".

Comment: So how do the observations in DF1 and DF2 relate?

Comment: Solved with a for cycle. Unfortunately due to the lack of common variables it was impossible to adopt aforementioned solutions.